# how to config apache2 and ubuntu server for my website

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, apache-2.4, configuration, static-ip

I have apache2 installed in ubuntu server and in local network its work but, when I try to connect from external network I have this error:

> Internet could not load the webpage because 192.168.1.xxx took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your internet connection.

Obviously when I try to connect with my website I digit my domain name in the address-bar but, then it change with the internal ip network!!!

Somebody have a solution for me?????

PS: In this moment the firewall is disabled!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect from internet to your local server, this server needs to communicate with the internet. In other words this server needs an external ip address. To get one you need to contact your ISP. 
If you have external IP address but it is an address of a router (or modem) you need to configure it to forward http ports (port 80) to your local machine. You do this in administration panel of the router.

Comment: I did!!! I have a static IP Address and I setted the rule in the port forward and in my domain panel! ... Infact when I digit my web address while the loading I see the change of my web address in local ip network (eg: http:/ / www.domainname.com -> http:/ / 192.168.1.xxx) .... why? and why can't open my website from external network?